# i have un-wanted data in some of my columns. How to get rid of it?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-science

as you can see down below in the **age** and **gender** column i have some data, whereas the value it should be either null or digit, why the cells clash with eachother? how to clean my columns?

And as i understood, the problem's source is the description column, there some cells appear empty/ or the data shows with some non-deletin spaces, whereas they have data, so when i read the file, the content of description shows in the age and the gender column

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/mtmedical_V6-16623.csv", header=True)
df.show(150)
```

output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         description|   medical_specialty|                 age|              gender|sample_name (What has been done to patient = Treatment)|       transcription|            keywords|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| A 23-year-old wh...| Allergy / Immuno...|                  23|              female|                                     Allergic Rhinitis |SUBJECTIVE:,  Thi...|allergy / immunol...|
| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|                null|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|PAST MEDICAL HIST...|bariatrics, lapar...|
| Consult for lapa...|          Bariatrics|                  42|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|"HISTORY OF PRESE...| at his highest h...|
| 2-D M-Mode. Dopp...| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                null|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D M-MODE: , ,1....|cardiovascular / ...|
|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                male|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|1.  The left vent...|cardiovascular / ...|
| Morbid obesity. ...|          Bariatrics|                  30|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|PREOPERATIVE DIAG...|bariatrics, gastr...|
| Liposuction of t...|                null|                null|                null|                                                   null|                null|                null|
|", Bariatrics,31,...|       1.  Deformity| right breast rec...|2.  Excess soft t...|                                    anterior abdomen...|3.  Lipodystrophy...|POSTOPERATIVE DIA...|
|  2-D Echocardiogram| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                male|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|2-D ECHOCARDIOGRA...|cardiovascular / ...|
| Suction-assisted...|          Bariatrics|                null|                male|                                    Lipectomy - Abdo...|PREOPERATIVE DIAG...|bariatrics, lipod...|
| Echocardiogram a...| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                null|                                    2-D Echocardiogr...|DESCRIPTION:,1.  ...|cardiovascular / ...|
| Morbid obesity. ...|          Bariatrics|                  50|                male|                                    Laparoscopic Gas...|PREOPERATIVE DIAG...|bariatrics, morbi...|
| Normal left vent...| Cardiovascular /...|                null|                male|                                           2-D Doppler |2-D STUDY,1. Mild...|cardiovascular / ...|
| Cerebral Angiogr...|           Neurology|                  31|                male|                                      Moyamoya Disease |"CC:, Confusion a...| she was found ""...|
```

[This is how the csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di4zb.png)

Comment: What does the original CSV look like for that row? the separator is probably also a character in the data, that isn't properly escaped.

Comment: @match, hey there, i uploaded the picture of the file, you can see it

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to map through the dataframe and drop the "bad rows". However, that won't be a very scalable process if you are getting several such csv files.

The Second alternative is to clean the `csv` file itself. It looks to me the file has incorrect tabs or space that could be problematic.

Lastly, you can try the following

```
val df = spark.read
.option("wholeFile", true)
.option("multiline",true)
.option("header", true)
.option("inferSchema", "true")
.csv("/FileStore/tables/mtmedical_V6-16623.csv")
```

This will get rid of textual content with multiple newlines which might be the issue here.

Comment: how to filter the rows that doesnt start with number?

Comment: df.filter("gender in ('male', 'female') ) will filter out record with incorrect gender. Similarly you can filter out the age if that doesn't in (1,2,....100).

Comment: i created a new column having the number from 1-4999, so the rows in which doesn't have any number will be deleted